# Liferay widget not visible on a specific liferay site/page

Tags: widget, liferay

I am working on a Liferay project and we developed our own widgets. And also our own sites of course. Now I have the problem that a specific widget is not available for a certain site. I can deploy it everywhere else, but not on this site.

Does anybody have an idea where this problem is coming from?

Greetings,
Michael

P.S. Please let me know if my question is not specific enough, I dont know how to be more clear here.

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript errors in your browser console? Maybe there is some code causing a non-working Drag-Drop of your widget to the layout? Or is your portlet not listed inside of the widget Section on the Add menu?

Comment: The problem is that it is not listed inside the widget section of the add menu. This problem only occurs on a specific page, not everywhere!

Comment: In your question you mention that you can't add a widget to any *site*, in your comment you mention *page*. Which of them is it? Is the widget completely absent, or greyed out in the "Add" menu? From your use of the term "widget" I'm assuming that you're referring to Liferay 7.1.x (what's x?)

Comment: @OlafKock: Sry for being unclear about it. I meant site, I cannot deploy it on any page of the site I want to deploy it on. It is absent in the widget list. Yes, Liferay 7.1.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention that

- you can deploy the widget on *any other site*
- you can't deploy the widget *on any page in a specific site*

I'm assuming that you're suffering from a lack of permissions. You can try to work around by becoming a global Administrator (I'm assuming that you're Site Administrator or Organization Administrator in the other sites, where you can add the widget).

Another alternative is that you're trying to add the widget to a site (or page) that's built from Templates that can't be changed: In that case, you'd not have any widget in the "Add Widget" menu though, if you have the "Add Widget" menu at all.

You may also want to check the overall permissions available for your custom widget in the Roles/Define Permission dialog and make sure that you're defining the correct permissions for your widget (e.g. check your widget's `default.xml` and its declaration)